# Is $g(x)=\log x$ convex function?

Tags: functions, logarithms, convex-analysis, self-learning

The graph of convex function is :

[image]

In a book it is written that $g(x)=\log x$ is strictly convex function.

So i searched for graph of $g(x)=\log x$ and found that

[image]

Though it has been said that $g(x)=\log x$ is strictly convex function, comparing these two graph it seems to me $g(x)=\log x$ is concave function .

Where am i doing mistake ?

Comment: It is (strictly) concave. However, some books or lecture notes use "convex" for both convex and concave, adding an adjective "upward" or "downward" -- which can be confusing.

Comment: @ClementC. Who would do such insanity?

Comment: @AlexR [well](http://people.reed.edu/~mayer/math111.html/header/node80.html)...

Comment: @AlexR It's not *that* strange. A concave function is a function for which the set below its graph is convex.

Comment: @Eff But convex optimisation will go havoc on concave functions :D

Comment: @ClementC. That killed me a little bit.

Comment: @AlexR If $f$ is a concave function, then $-f$ is convex, so not if you do a small change.

Comment: Well, pick a better book!

Comment: @Eff Then the problem changes. $\min f \not\equiv \min -f$.

Comment: The whole point is -- even though this terminology pisses and stuns me a bit (I do find it eery and confusing), it's important to know it exists.

Comment: @AlexR, the point remains that concave functions are ubiquitous in convex optimization. They just have to be used in different ways. Calling them "convex upward" makes sense in that context, though believe me, I don't like it.

Comment: I have to say I learned something today. I frankly had no idea that this whole "upward/downward" business is as common as it is. I Googled "concave upward" and my mind was blown. Grr, how grating.

Comment: So tree, would you mind sharing with us exactly what book you got this from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function $g(x)$ is a concave. You can see from your graph that the line passing through two given points on the curve lies *below* the graph of $g$, not above the graph (which you would get with a convex function).

Answer (score 27):

The function is concave if it's second derivative is negative. We have that
$$
g''(x)=(\log(x))''=\biggl(\frac1x\biggr)'=-\frac1{x^2}
$$
for $x>0$. Hence, $g(x)$ is a concave function.